# NGINX is hanging while another PHP-FPM script is running

Tags: php, nginx

I noticed a weird behavior which I can't explain. I'm running Nginx on Debian 10 with php7.3-fpm

Consider the following script:

```
<?php
sleep(60); // or anything that takes times
?>
```

If I request this page, then request any other PHP page on the website, the "normal" page will hang and won't load until the "slow" page finishes loading. It's like the webserver isn't handling more than 1 thread.

If I request static content instead it will load normally, which points me to a php-fpm problem.

Here is my php-fpm configuration (I've already bumped up values from the default):

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 6
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 8
```

Would appreciate any ideas before I ditch everything and re build the server from scratch...

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using sessions? (Auto-started perhaps, if not explicitly?) If so - PHP puts a lock on the session data file, as long as one script instance is still using it, and other scripts trying to access the same session, will have to wait. (Using `session_write_close` as soon as possible in long-running scripts can help with that.)

Comment: @CBroe spot on! turns out if I load the 2nd page from a different browser while the first page is loading, it loads instantly. I was so sure it was a server configuration issue, I only tested from the same browser session. I'll try to close sessions early in long running scripts. Thanks a lot!